# Using sublime regex to find all links that dont start with "home" word

Tags: regex, ember.js, handlebars.js, sublimetext2

I am using handlebars. So I need a way to detect all `{{#link-to 'route-name'}}...` helpers that dont start with home name. I am new to regex so I cannot find good regex. Bad example: `([^home]|^) {{#link-to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `[^...]` term, which means any character except those in the brackets, so `[^home]` should match any character except for `h`, `o`, `m` and `e`.

In your case, what you're searching for is a Negative Lookahead:

```
^.+\s?{{#link-to '(?:(?!home).{0,4}.*)'}}
```

Take a look at this [Regex101 working example](https://regex101.com/r/qkIpqS/3).

- `^` Matches start of a text (or line, with /m flag enabled)
- `.+` Matches the name of the element (You may remove it if needed)
- `\s?` Matches one or zero occurrences of a whitespace character (`\s`, you also may remove)
- `{{#link-to '` The literal form of the text to be matched
- `(?:` Start of a non-capturing group
- `(?!` Start of a negative lookahead group
- `home` Literal text to NOT be matched
- `)` End of the negative lookahead group
- `.{0,4}` Matches any zero-four characters except if they value is `home` (because of the `(?!home)`)
- `.*` If the link-to's name is longer than four characters, match them.
- `)` End of the non-capturing group
- `'}}` Literal text to match (end of the route link)

Comment: Sry maybe question is not clear so home is `{{#link-to 'home.example-sub-route'}}` Not text name it is route name so this example shoud be ignored, but if I have in app `{{#link-to 'not-home'}}` then I should get result

Comment: Perfect !:) Thank you on your time realy detailed explanation and perfect solution :)